# average 3rd column when 1st and 2nd column have same numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

just lets make it simple, assume that I have a 10x3 matrix in matlab. The numbers in the first two columns in each row represent the x and y (position) and the number in 3rd columns show the corresponding value. For instance, `[1 4 12]` shows that the value of function in x=1 and y=4 is equal to 12. I also have same x, and y in different rows, and I want to **average** the values with same x,y. and replace all of them with averaged one.

For example :

```
A = [1 4 12 
     1 4 14
     1 4 10
     1 5 5
     1 5 7];
```

I want to have

```
B = [1 4 12
     1 5 6]
```

I really appreciate your help
Thanks
Ali

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
A = [1 4 12;1 4 14;1 4 10; 1 5 5;1 5 7];
[x,y] = consolidator(A(:,1:2),A(:,3),@mean);
B = [x,y]
B =
     1     4    12
     1     5     6
```

[Consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354-consolidator) is on the File Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Using built-in functions:

```
sparsemean = accumarray(A(:,1:2), A(:,3).', [], @mean, 0, true);
[i,j,v] = find(sparsemean);
B = [i.' j.' v.'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1 4 12;1 4 14;1 4 10; 1 5 5;1 5 7]; %your example data
B = unique(A(:, 1:2), 'rows'); %find the unique xy pairs
C = nan(length(B), 1);

% calculate means
for ii = 1:length(B)
    C(ii) = mean(A(A(:, 1) == B(ii, 1) & A(:, 2) == B(ii, 2), 3));
end

C =
    12
     6
```

The step inside the `for` loop uses logical indexing to find the mean of rows that match the current xy pair in the loop.

Comment: Note that you don't need the tests in that loop. unique returns some extra information that can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unique` to get the unique rows and use the returned indexing array to find the ones that should be averaged and ask `accumarray` to do the averaging part:

```
[C,~,J]=unique(A(:,1:2), 'rows');
B=[C, accumarray(J,A(:,3),[],@mean)];
```

For your example

```
>> [C,~,J]=unique(A(:,1:2), 'rows')
C =
     1     4
     1     5
J =
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
```

`C` contains the unique rows and `J` shows which rows in the original matrix correspond to the rows in `C` then

```
>> accumarray(J,A(:,3),[],@mean)
ans =
    12
     6
```

returns the desired averages and

```
>> B=[C, accumarray(J,A(:,3),[],@mean)]
B =
     1     4    12
     1     5     6
```

is the answer.